# Java trying to use Lambda expressions with Runnable to pass parameters in multi-threading tasking

Tags: java, lambda, scope, anonymous-inner-class

Basically I'm trying to add a *runnable* class to a **tasking threading class** of my own which *executes* these tasks on a different thread, I need to pass the parameters to the *runnable* object, but I'm having trouble passing strings as the compiler tells:

"Local variable receiver defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

```
String message = networkMessage.getString();
Game.getInstance().addGameTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Game.getInstance().playerTalk(player.getId(), message);
            }
});
```

I tried using **Lambda with Runnable** to do something as simpler as:

```
Runnable r = () -> Game.getInstance().playerTalk(player.getId(), mode, receiver, channelId, message);
```

But the compiler will say the same error.

In C# I would come up with something as simple as:

```
Game.AddGameTask(() => { Game.PlayerTalk(_player.Id, message, mode, receiver, channelId); });
```

What can I attempt to achieve something as simple as that? It's task is supposed to be for a game server, so I need to add these "tasks" to an external thread for better functioning and performance.

What is wrong?

Comment: this has **nothing** to do with threading

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to make the `receiver` variable final, which means once its value is set it cannot be set again. E.g.

```
final Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
```

Alternatively you could use an `AtomicReference` to hold the object and allow access in a thread safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark `message`, `player` as `final`, like:

```
final String message = networkMessage.getString();
Game.getInstance().addGameTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Game.getInstance().playerTalk(player.getId(), message);
            }
});
```

This way the lambda version will work.
This is a(n implementation) decision for the Java Language (not present in C#, that is the reason it works there).

Comment: Not sure where `player` comes from... If it is a member variable, it does not have to be `final`, but if it on the stack, it should be.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure why are there people who thinks this is a wrong answer for the question, or this should be deleted. Could you elaborate? (I answered before the question was marked as a duplicate.)